# Why do I get 'list index out of range' although the times-list values are there?

Tags: python, function, dictionary, iteration, indexoutofboundsexception

### Introduction

Firstly, thank you so much for taking the time to look at my question and code. I know my coding needs improving, but as with all new things it times time to perfect.

### **Background**

I am making use of different functions to do the following:

1. Import multiple files (3 for now). Each files contains time, pressure and void columns.
2. Store the lists in dictionaries. Eg. All the pressures in one pressure dictionary.
3. Filter the **pressure** data and ensure that I still have the corresponding number of **time** data points (for each file).

I call these functions in the main function.

### Problem

Everything runs perfectly until I run the time loop in the DataFilter function for a second time. However, I did check that I can access all three different lists for pressure and time in the dictionaries. Why do I get 'index out of range' at this point:`t=timeFROMtimes [i]` when the function runs a second time? [This is the output I get for the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVpZb.jpg)

### Code

```
#IMPORT LIBRARIES
import glob
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt, numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import spline

#INPUT PARAMETERS
max_iter = 3 #maximum number of iterations
i = 0 #starting number of iteration
tcounter = 0
number_of_files = 3 #number of files in directory
sourcePath = 'C:\\Users\\*' #not displaying actual directory
list_of_source_files = glob.glob(sourcePath + '/*.TXT')
pressures = {} #initialize a dictionary
times ={} #initialize a dictionary

#GET SPECIFIC FILE & PRESSURE, TIME VALUES 
def Get_source_files(list_of_source_files,i):
    #print('Get_source_files')
    with open(list_of_source_files[i]) as source_file:
        print("file entered:",i+1)
        lst = [] 
        for line in source_file:
            lst.append([ float(x) for x in line.split()])
        time = np.array([ x[0] for x in lst]) #first row in file and make array
        void = np.array([ x[1] for x in lst]) #second row in file and make array
        pressure =(np.array([ x[2] for x in lst]))*-1 #etc. & change the sign of the imported pressure data
    return pressure,time

#SAVE THE TIME AND PRESSURE IN DICTIONARIES
def SaveInDictionary (Pressure,time,i):
    #print('SaveInDictionary')
    pressures[i]=[Pressure]
    times[i]=[time]
    return pressures,times

#FILTER PRESSURE DATA AND ADJUST TIME
def FilterData (pressureFROMpressures,timeFROMtimes,i):
    print('FilterData')
    t=timeFROMtimes [i]
    p=pressureFROMpressures[i]
    data_points=int((t[0]-t[-1])/-0.02) #determine nr of data points per column of the imported file
    filtered_pressure = [] #create an empty list for the filtered pressure
    pcounter = 0 #initiate a counter
    tcounter = 0
    time_new =[0,0.02] #these initial values are needed for the for-loop

    for j in range(data_points): 
        if p[j]<8: #filter out all garbage pressure data points above 8 bar
            if p[j]>0:
                filtered_pressure.append(p[j]) #append the empty list ofsave all the new pressure values in new_pressure
                pcounter += 1

    for i in range(pcounter-1):
        time_new[0]=0
        time_new[i+1]=time_new[i]+0.02 #add 0.02 to the previous value
        time_new.append(time) #append the time list
        tcounter += 1 #increment the counter
    del time_new[-1] #somehow a list of the entire time is formed at the end that should be removed
    return filtered_pressure, time_new

#MAIN!!
P = list()
while (i <= number_of_files and i!=max_iter):
    pressure,time = Get_source_files(list_of_source_files,i) #return pressure and time from specific file
    pressures, times = SaveInDictionary (pressure,time,i)#save pressure and time in the dictionaries
    i+=1 #increment i to loop
print('P1=',pressures[0])
print('P2=',pressures[1])
print('P3=',pressures[2])
print('t1=',times[0])
print('t2=',times[1])
print('t3=',times[2])

#I took this out of the main function to check my error:
for i in range(2):
    filtered_pressure,changed_time = FilterData(pressures[i],times[i],i)
    finalP, finalT = SaveInDictionary (filtered_pressure,changed_time,i)#save pressure and time in the dictionaries
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation. I tried to copy/paste your code, but it won't work because of indentation errors. Also, please provide the traceback of the error you're getting.

Comment: @CoryMadden, I have fixed the indentation and added an image of the output I get. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the loop you took out of the main function you already index into `times`, but in the

```
#I took this out of the main function to check my error:
for i in range(2):
    filtered_pressure,changed_time = FilterData(pressures[i],times[i],i)
    # Here you call FilterData with times[i]
```

but in the FilterData function, where you call the passed variable `timeFROMtimes` you index it again with `i`:

```
def FilterData (pressureFROMpressures,timeFROMtimes,i):
    print('FilterData')
    t=timeFROMtimes [i]  # <-- right here
```

This seems odd. Try removing one of the index operators (`[i]`) and also do so for `pressures`.

### Edit

As @strubbly pointed out, in your `SaveInDictionary` function you assign the value `[Pressure]`. The square brackets denote a list with one element, the numpy array `Pressure`. This can be seen in your error message, by the opening bracket before the arrays when you print P1-3 and t1-3.
To directly save your numpy array, loose the brackets:

```
def save_in_dictionary(pressure_array, time, i):
    pressures[i] = pressure_array
    times[i] = time
    return pressures, times
```

Comment: Yeah - it'll need a little more of a change than that - since the OP builds the entries in the dictionary as a 1 element list.  That needs changing too.

Comment: @m00am, thank you for the answer. I have removed the index operators `([i])`for both `times` and `pressures`, but by doing that I get this error: `TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars`

Comment: @strubbly, will you please elaborate on what you mean with the dictionary being a 1 element list?

Comment: @strubbly Indeed. Thanks for pointing that out. I overred that when I stormed out for lunch ;)

Comment: @m00am, sorry I reacted too quickly. You saw I removed my comment because I managed to fix it. My code works perfectly now. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @I.Uni No problem :)